# JMeter - how to simulate polling with multiple URLs

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

In JMeter, I can load test many pages using a random variable:

`/path/item/${random_var}`

I would like to hit each page X number of times (or until a condition is met). I would also like to wait (e.g. 1 second) in between requests for a specific page (it's fine to have concurrent requests for `/path/item/1` and `/path/item/2`).

Any guidance on setup for that is much appreciated. I can answer clarifying questions if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Add a [Constant Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer) as a child of this request and set `Thread Delay` to 1000.

Timer will be fired before each request therefore you will get a 1 second delay between next call. Sleep time will not be added to sampler's response time (unless you are using [Transaction Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller) configured to do so)

See [A Comprehensive Guide to Using JMeter Timers](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/comprehensive-guide-using-jmeter-timers) for more information on above and other Timers and their use cases.